# Yii2 Upload | Bad Request (#400) Missing required parameters: id

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, yii2-advanced-app

I have trouble uploading files.
Press Save. Then message error "Bad Request (# 400) Missing required parameters: id".

I had tried by doing $ model-> save (false); but when I do so, only uploads the text, and not the images.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qDAA.png)

File backend\views\album\ _form.php

```html
<?= $form->field($model, 'file')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'initialPreview'=>[],
        'allowedFileExtensions'=>['jpg', 'png','gif'],
        'showPreview' => true,
        'showRemove' => true,
        'showUpload' => false
     ]
   ]); ?>
```

File backend\models\Album.php

```html
  public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'album';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['album_name', 'album_detail', 'album_cover', 'album_create', 'album_status'], 'required'],
            [['album_create'], 'safe'],
            [['album_status'], 'string'],
            [['file'],'file'],
            [['album_name', 'album_cover'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['album_detail'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }
```

File backend\controllers\AlbumController.php

```html
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Album();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
        {
            // get the instance of the uploaded file
            $imageName = $model->album_name;
            $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
            $model->file->saveAs( 'uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension );

            // save the path in the db column
            $model->album_cover =  'uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
            $model->save();

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can u show URL where u get Bad Request 400?

Answer (score 0):

In `actionCreate()` u're not checking if `save()` was successfull. Add:

```
if($model->save()) {
   return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
}
```

Remove `else` statement from:

```
 else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Leave just:

```
return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
```

Propably your model is not saving, running it like u said `$model->save(false)` save it without any validation. Try to debug why it's not saving, in easiest way, after `$model->save()` or `$model->validate()`:

```
var_dump($model->errors);die;
```